# How does "endpoint" work in zmq?

Tags: undefined, zeromq

Why this code prints "undefined" instead of "tcp://127.0.0.1:8888"

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var rp = zmq.socket('req');
rp.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8888')
console.log(rp.endpoint);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A:** Because a **`zmq.socket`**-instance does not have any **`.endpoint`** attribute ( or method )

For available ZeroMQ API-services, check the options available in documentation